# Button.Click event doesn't fire if datagridview is in editmode

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridView (unbound for several reasons). 
When the user changes something I am saving the new value in a tempTable

```
 Private Sub fgFields_AfterEdit(sender As Object, e As C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.RowColEventArgs) Handles fgFields.AfterEdit
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
    SaveField(e.Row)
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```

I have also a button (btnSave) that saves the values from datagrid , among with other values to a database:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    SaveFileDef("SAVE")
End Sub
```

My problem is that if I start editing the cell  I need to click somewhere else to fire the after_edit. If the user click on btnSave the event After_Edit is fired but not the button.Click!!!!

So the code in the event btnSave.Click is not running.

Any ideas how to overcome this strange behaviour?

Comment: what SaveFileDef does .. ?

Comment: Just save some info to the database. But I want to run it only if the user click on the button

Comment: Same with SaveField does ?

Comment: No it does a different job (otherwise there is no problem at all)

Comment: try my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So .. you use ComponentOne Flexgrid ..

try this way on **Event RowValidating**

```
 e.Cancel = True
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.The event doesn't fire. So this part of code doesn't play any role.( I tried of course)

Comment: How is componentOne related to datagridView on the question?

Comment: Can't you this **Private Sub fgFields_AfterEdit(sender As Object, e As C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.RowColEventArgs) Handles fgFields.AfterEdit** in the question above ? .. That's not the usual Datagridview ..